# Why is this error coming up when building Gradle project ? Using gradle version 3.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'rightskillnow-parent'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.6.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.6.
> > Could not get resource 'http://repo.springsource.org/plugins-release/org/springframework/build/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.6/propdeps-plugin-0.0.6.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://repo.springsource.org/plugins-release/org/springframework/build/gradle/propdeps-plugin/0.0.6/propdeps-plugin-0.0.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. An error trace is usually not enough information to help you. Include your code, in this case the build script, as a [mcve]. See also [ask]. That said, when I use `curl -I` with the URL in your error message, I also get a 403 error, and just using `curl` without `-I` states why: HTTP is not supported. Change your dependency URLs to use https:// instead of http://. This is probably a good idea anyway; you wouldn't want to build your software with libraries anybody can mess with in transit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to repo.springsource.org over HTTP was disabled on 15 January 2020 having been [announced](https://spring.io/blog/2019/09/16/goodbye-http-repo-spring-use-https) on 16 September 2019. You should switch to HTTPS instead. You may also want to switch to `repo.spring.io` to avoid the redirect from `repo.springsource.org`. This would make your repository URL `https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release` rather than `http://repo.springsource.org/plugins-release` which you appear to be using at the moment.